# scripts not working with url rewrite (i tried non relative links)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I know there are like 5 questions on this topic, and i have been through them all but couldn't find any answer. I just got into URL rewriting today so i am very new (and bad at it), and this is what I have

Root folder

```
index.php
.htaccess
-scripts
     script.js
     jquery.js
-styles
     style.css
```

.htaccess folder

```
 (url= index.php?catID=1  URLREWRITE = index/1)

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^/?index/([0-9]+)$ index.php?catID=$1
```

index.php

```
 <script src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="/scripts/script.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
```

Errors

```
 GET http://localhost/scripts/jquery.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) 
 //This one multiple times for every script/css i have
```

As you can see it tried to add / before the script but this didn't change anything.
I really don't need a clever answer, the only thing i need is the url replaced like you can see in the .htaccess folder.

thanks very much

Comment: maybe this is usefull: path to my root folder xampp/htdocs/websites/nicms

Comment: Before the `RewriteRule`, I think you need a `RewriteCond` that checks if the url is for `index.php` & possibly a `RewriteCond` for the query string. That way it won't try to rewrite any url other than the `index.php`. I've used https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test before.

Comment: I use `.htaccess` to route every single request to a `route.php` file & then handle all the complexities through PHP. So I hardly ever mess with the `.htaccess`

Comment: "path to my root folder" - And the root folder is where `index.php`, `.htaccess` and the `scripts` and `styles` subdirectories are located I assume? So, is `http://localhost/scripts/jquery.js` not the correct URL-path? If you request this file directly you get a 404? If you remove `.htaccess` and request the file directly do you still get a 404?

Comment: @Reed The regex only matches a URL of the form `/index/1234` (it wouldn't match `index.php` or `/scripts` or `/styles` requests) - so there wouldn't seem to be a need for additional conditions.

Comment: @NielsVanSteen You are correct in using root-relative URLs here - if you weren't then that would give your more (404) problems.

Comment: @MrWhite Yes it gives a 404 with and without the .htaccess. And yes the root folder is where all the pages are

Comment: Then there would seem to be something else wrong with your config that is causing this? What happens if you request `localhost/index.php` directly? Did you not have a working site _before_ implementing `.htaccess`?

Comment: it works when i do localhost/websites/nicms/index.php, and only if i do it like this (without htaccess). And i do have a bigger website (it's a project i'm doing for my internship) but it's not online if thats what you're asking.

Comment: That would seem to suggest your **document root** is `xampp/htdocs` and not `xampp/htdocs/websites/nicms` as you've stated? The document root is defined in the server config and is the root of your public HTML space. Your script URLs should therefore be: `/website/nicems/scripts/jquery.js`. (?) What you are calling the "root folder" would seem to be just the location of where you have put these files? There's nothing that actually _defines_ this as a "root folder"?

Comment: It looks like you need to have a rethink about your desired URL structure. If this is an entirely separate site then consider creating another virtual host and keeping it separate. Your site can be located anywhere on your machine, it doesn't need to be inside `xampp/htdocs`. In fact, it would probably be better if it's not (after all, isn't that where the default xampp website lives?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MrWhite i found a solution.

I added this to the script

```
<script src="//localhost/websites/nicms/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

This is the entire URL to my website folder. It also worked without the //localhost
in front of it like @MrWhite said.

Like this

```
  <script src="/websites/nicms/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

For anyone reading through (and myself) once the website will be online the path won't localhost anymore but the domain name.

I solved this by making 1 variable in php so i can change it easily later

PHP

```
<?php 
   $url = "//localhost/websites/nicms/";
?>
<script src="<?php echo $url; ?>scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```